# Chef - supervisor_service conflict with already service'd programs (nginx in this case)?

Tags: chef-infra

I am using opcode's cookbooks: application_python, nginx and supervisor.

stack:  ubuntu 14.04, django, nginx, gunicorn, postgresql

application_python wants to launch django apps using gunicorn and supervisor, as the service controller, seems recommended.

Perhaps naively, I thought why not run everything under supervisor?

So I ended up with something like this:

**install nginx (tried both of these approaches, same issue)**

```
include_recipe 'nginx::default'
#include_recipe 'nginx::package'
```

further in the processing...

**launch nginx via supervisor**

```
supervisor_service "nginx" do
  command "nginx"
  process_name "nginx"
  #using :restart instead didn't help
  action [:enable, :start]
end
```

Problem - my supervisor nginx can't seem to stay up.  Looking through supervisorctl:

```
supervisor> status
bemyerp                          RUNNING   pid 14724, uptime 0:00:56
nginx                            STARTING  
supervisor> status
bemyerp                          RUNNING   pid 14724, uptime 0:01:10
nginx                            STARTING
```

and the log:

/var/log/supervisor/nginx-stderr---supervisor-Lyi21Z.log

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8000 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8000 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8000 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

And indeed, there was already an up and running nginx, launched on Ubuntu's service:

```
root@vagrant:~# service --status-all
 [ + ]  apparmor
....
 [ + ]  nginx
 [ ? ]  ondemand
 [ + ]  postgresql
....
 [ + ]  supervisor
....
```

I tracked it down to

https://github.com/miketheman/nginx/blob/master/recipes/default.rb

```
include_recipe "nginx::#{node['nginx']['install_method']}"

service 'nginx' do
  supports :status => true, :restart => true, :reload => true
  action :start
end
```

I also see this in my chef execution log, right around the point where I would hit supervisor_service nginx

```
WARN: Cloning resource attributes for service[nginx] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
WARN: Previous service[nginx]: /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/nginx/recipes/default.rb:24:in `from_file'
WARN: Current  service[nginx]: /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/basedjango/recipes/default.rb:153:in `from_file'
```

From a quick google on 3694, I can't tell if it's causing this issue or if it is just a chatty warning message folks would rather not see.

I can't find an off-switch attribute in nginx cookbook to NOT start the service and code above doesn't have any conditionals anyway.

postgresql has the same launch-on-install behavior as well.

Question: am I missing something obvious?

How does the supervisor service play with installed programs that pack their own built-in service launch?  Does the supervisor_service resource have something to handle that?

How do programs like nginx and postgres integrate with configurations where the admins want to use a particular service manager?

Should I just skip using supervisor in these cases and only use to manage un-launched programs?  Not a huge deal-breaker, but this isn't mentioned anywhere that I see.

I thought turning off the service explicitly **before** the supervisor_service nginx step might do the trick, but it hasn't.

```
service "nginx" do
  action [:stop, :disable]
end
```

last, but not least, version info:

```
root@vagrant:~# chef-client -v
Chef: 11.14.6

application_python (3.0.0)
nginx (2.7.4)
supervisor (0.4.12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as you have found, is that all other cookbooks will rely on the plain `service` resource. When you use `service` it will default to using the [system provider](https://docs.getchef.com/resource_service.html#providers) that Chef has set in it for your platform (or figures out what it should be at run time come v12).

#### The `service` resource

One way you could get around this is by creating a complete `service` provider for supervisor that [implements all the required functions](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/1241ea6f9866d0e61d11129bb32e5fc96cd2bac0/lib/chef/provider/service.rb). The supervisor cookbooks light weight [`service` provider](https://github.com/poise/supervisor/blob/master/providers/service.rb) does some of it already so the extension into the full, heavy weight, offical service provider shouldn't be too hard. Then calls to `service` can go to supervisor.

The first issue with that is getting your services to support `supervisor`. By default a package that is installed on your system will come with sysvinit or upstart or systemd config but very few (if any) would come with supervisor config. This needs to come from somewhere.

Next issue is you need Chef to detect that supervisor should be the default provider, or default for those services you want under supervisor. There was an [open feature request](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3371) to do this generically but it doesn't look have had any work done or even made it across in the move from Jira to Github.

#### A possible solution

The way I can think of to work around both of those is to create a [wrapper cookbook](http://www.getchef.com/blog/2013/12/03/doing-wrapper-cookbooks-right/) for any cookbook that you really want to use supervise. In that cookbook you can configure the service in supervisor up front as you did with `nginx`

```
supervisor_service "nginx" do
  command       "nginx"
  process_name  "nginx"
  action        :enable
end
```

Then make the `service` resource use the supervisor provider.

```
Chef::Platform.set :platform => :linux, :resource => :service, :provider => Chef::Provider::Service::Supervisor
```

Apart from that all other config gets passed down to the original underlying cookbook.

The underlying cookbook could still have logic in them to reset that provider, although few would mess with `service`. Also I'm not sure of the scope that `Chef::Platform.set` works on. I would guess the entire run but ymmv.

***Basically***, use the standard service manager for services that support it. Life will be easier.

Comment: Yes, I am thinking that the standard service will do.  Why complicate things?  But I am surprised this isn't mentioned as a gotcha on the supervisor cookbook for example.  Chef seems very powerful, but I find myself stumbling around in the dark a good deal of the time.

Comment: True, supervisor would be the place to mention it. Maybe create a git pull request for the README?  Although I say life will be easier using the default service manager, even attempting the above will teach you a lot about how Chef works. Chef only really started making sense to me after I created and debugged a few complete cookbooks (including libraries, and heavy weight providers/resources) and messed around with the internals a bit (patching the windows service provider).  Although it's a nice easy DSL on top, there'e a lot of complexity underneath to achieve that.